# What is a good .mp3/.m4v tag editor for OS X

Tags: macos, mp3, tags, m4v

What is  a good .mp3/.m4v tag editor for OS X that's not iTunes?

I'd prefer free but I'm open to anything.

I've looked at [ID3 Editor](http://www.pa-software.com/products/overview.php?prod=BC3B2E3A) but that only does .mp3 (from what I could see).

I want to set my own values so no need for an auto-tagger.

Comment: Are you looking for an auto tagger or a simple editor?

Comment: ID3 is good in Windows, never used it in OS X, and I just used it for mp3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Easytag](http://web.archive.org/web/20180105090358/https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG) is available through Fink:

```
fink install easytag
```

Homebrew:

```
brew install easy-tag
```

and MacPorts:

```
port install easytag
```

Marco Schuh produced an [unofficial native build](http://marcoschuh.de/wp/?page_id=411), though it seems the file is currently (Feb. 2018) offline.

Comment: Have you used this under OS X?  If so, how well does it work for you?

Comment: i used fink a long time ago, i don't have a mac anymore but at the time every application in there that i tried worked so i have no reason to believe that easytag wouldn't.

Comment: available as a homebrew for osx as well. 'brew install easy-tag'

Comment: you can also download a '.dmg' native for osx at http://marcoschuh.de/wp/static/files/EasyTAG_alpha5.dmg

Comment: you can also download a '.dmg' native for osx at http://marcoschuh.de/wp/static/files/EasyTAG_alpha5.dmg

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested in this also - I've tried a few MP3 taggers to no avail as all have so far paled in comparison to Tag&Rename which is still Windows only - I still run VirtualBox for this one application.

For .m4v files I've been using the wonderful MetaX - have used this for my entire DVD collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Swiss Army knife Mp3tag right within Mac OS. Take a look here:

[More MP3 guessing pattern with Mp3tag in Mac OS](http://www.leniel.net/2011/05/more-mp3-guessing-pattern-mp3tag-mac-os.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but I use Media Rage.

http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/15255/media-rage

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using the command line, including compiling from source, check out [ID3 mass tagger](http://home.wanadoo.nl/squell/id3.html).

After using it a bit myself, I definitely think it should have been included in OS X as default!

EDIT: Oh, and it's free and open source (obviously).

Comment: Thanks but it's not for me and the user that needs it is far from command line savvy

Answer (score 0):

Best command line mp4 tag editor is libmp4v2 http://resare.com/libmp4v2/

Just compile and instale and it works fine (of course you need installed the development tools in your mac).

Answer (score 0):

I just found [TriTag](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15407/tritag) from [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020988/change-title-of-mp3-in-id3-tags-to-the-file-name), and it worked great for me. It works for MP3, don't know about other formats.